# Array in Swift returning error

Tags: arrays, variables, swift, random, words

I am trying to create a variable that gets a random word from an array. I am using the method below to find it however it give me an error *"Missing return function expected to return 'String"*

```
let array: [String] = ["Example1", "Example2"]

var chooseOne: String {

        [Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.array.count)))]

    }
```

How do I get the function to work? 
I am brand new to swift, and any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should select an answer

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1) You need a return in there.  Computed properties (i.e. `var propertyName: Type { someCalculation }`) aren’t like closures (where simple 1-line expressions can skip the return statement and have it be the value of the expression).

2) Assuming you want a value from the array, you need to actually index into the array.

```
var chooseOne: String {

    return array[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.array.count)))]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should return string:

```
    var chooseOne: String {

        return "\(Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.array.count))))"

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you missed to add the `return` statement:

```
return [Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.array.count)))]
^^^^^^
```

However the code has another error: you are not specifying the array. The correct way is:

```
return  self.array[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.array.count)))]
        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable should return String.

```
let array = ["Example1", "Example2"]

var chooseOne: String {

    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))

    return array[randomIndex]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is what I use for the random selection of something from an array:

```
func function_name() -> return_type  {
            ^                 ^
        var unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(diceImages.count)
        var unsignedRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
        var randomNumber = Int(unsignedRandomNumber)

        return array_name[randomNumber]
                    ^
    }
```

I put a carrot underneath of the code that is specific to the situation you use it in.